# Is every edge between articulation points a bridge?

Tags: graph-theory

In an undirected graph,

Is it true that every edge between two articulation points is a bridge?

It seems pretty straightforward, but I can't think of a rigorous proof.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your "non-rigorous" proof go? How does it apply to the graph with vertices $u,v,w,x,y$ and edges $uv,vw,wu,ux,vy$ (the self-complementary graph of order $5$)? What are the articulation points and what are the bridges in this graph?